# Creating a function that gets a server cookie for authentication in NextJS14

Tags: typescript, next.js, cookies, app-router, nextjs-api-router

I am trying to implement an email address verification feature when someone registers my NextJS website with a WordPress installation as a headless CMS. To do this I want to do the following:

1. Setting a server token whose value is

```
{id: <user_id_in_WP_user_database_>, token: <token_fetched_from_REST_API_endpoint>}
```

2. Sending an email to the user through nodemailer and expecting him to redirect to my (/verified) route where I get the cookie I set, so I can authenticate him (using another WP REST API endpoint) and then update his status to authorized in WP user database

The problem with all this is that I can't get my cookie value when the user checks the email and redirects (as the function returns undefined). From Chrome developer tools, I can see that the cookie is there and if I manually type my Route handler URL (/API/cookie) I get the expected result (cookie value).

Here you can see my route handler `api/cookie` that sets and gets the cookie depending on the HTTP method:

```
// API route that validates the user's token by storing it in a cookie
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { cookies } from "next/headers";

// Export function for GET method
export async function GET(req: NextRequest) {
  // GET request to fetch the verification cookie
  try {
    // Stores the verification cookie
    const cookie = cookies().get("verify")?.value
    console.log('Getting cookie: ', cookies().has("verify"));
    // Checks if the cookie exists
    if (cookie == undefined) {
      return new NextResponse(JSON.stringify({error: 'Missing verification cookie.'}), {status: 400});
    }
    // Returns the cookie
    else {
      return new NextResponse(cookie, {status: 200});
    }
  // Exception error handler
  } 
  catch (error) {
  console.error('Error during verification:', error);
  return new NextResponse(JSON.stringify({error}), {status: 500});;
  }

}

export async function POST(req: NextRequest) {
  try {
    const body = await req.json();
    console.log('POST request body: ', body)
    // Expires one hour after the email is sent
    const expires = new Date(Date.now() + 60 * 60 * 1000);
    cookies().set("verify", JSON.stringify(body), { expires, httpOnly: true });
    console.log('cookie created: ', cookies().has('verify'))
    return new NextResponse(body, {status: 200});;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error);
    return new NextResponse(JSON.stringify({error: 'Server error while creating cookie.'}), {status: 500});;
  }
}
```

Here you can see the `/verified` server route that the user redirects from the email:

```
'use server'

import MaxWidthWrapper from "@/components/MaxWidthWrapper";
import { buttonVariants } from "@/components/ui/button";
import Link from "next/link";
import { wp_fetch } from "@/lib/wp-fetch";
import { Url } from "next/dist/shared/lib/router/router";
import { verify } from "@/lib/verify";

export default  async function Verified() {

  let verified: String;
  let buttonText: String;
  let buttonRedirect: Url;

  async function isVerified () {
    const wpVerified = await verify();
    if (typeof wpVerified == 'string'){
      verified = wpVerified;
      buttonText = 'Return to register form';
      buttonRedirect = '/register';
      return {verified, buttonText, buttonRedirect};
    }
    else {
      const authenticated = await wp_fetch('PUT', `users/${wpVerified.id}?roles=subscriber`, {roles: 'subscriber'});
      if(authenticated.id){
        verified = 'Your registration to <span className="text-rose-500">NextJStore</span> has been verified.';
        buttonText = 'Please return to homepage and login with your account.';
        buttonRedirect = '/';
        return {verified, buttonText, buttonRedirect};
      }
      else{
        verified = 'Internal server error. Please try again.';
        buttonText = 'Return to register form';
        buttonRedirect = '/register';
        return  {verified, buttonText, buttonRedirect};
      }
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <MaxWidthWrapper>
        <div className="py-20 mx-auto text-center flex flex-col items-center max-w-3xl">
          <h1 className="text-3xl font-bold tracking-tight text-gray-700 sm:text-5xl">
            {(await isVerified()).verified}
          </h1>
          <p className="mt-6 text-lg max-w-prose text-muted-foreground">
            {(await isVerified()).buttonText}
          </p>
          <div className="flex flex-col sm:flex-row gap-4 mt-6">
            {/* buttonVariants() applies default styles of the button component. With parameters, the styles change */}
            <Link href={(await isVerified()).buttonRedirect} className={buttonVariants()}>
              Return
            </Link>
          </div>
        </div>
      </MaxWidthWrapper>
    </>
  );
}
```

And here is the `verify.ts` helper function that I call in the route without parameters

```
import { sendEmail } from "@/app/api/cookie/mailer";
import SMTPTransport from "nodemailer/lib/smtp-transport";

export async function verify(username?: string, email?: string, password?: string, id?: number) {
  if (username && email && password && id){
    const wpAppCredentials = {
      username: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_WP_ADMIN_USERNAME,
      password: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_WP_REGISTER_APP_PASSWORD,
    };
    const encryptedWpAppCredentials = btoa(`${wpAppCredentials.username}:${wpAppCredentials.password}`);
    const tokenFetch = await fetch(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_JWT_BASE + 'token', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({username, password}),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `Basic ${encryptedWpAppCredentials}`
      },
    });
    const json = await tokenFetch.json()
    console.log('Token:', json)
    if(tokenFetch.ok){
      const token = json.token
      // Sends a verification email to the user
      const mailer: SMTPTransport.SentMessageInfo = await sendEmail(username, email, 'VERIFY');
      const res = await fetch(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DEPLOY_URL + '/api/cookie', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: `{"token": "${token}", "id": "${id}"}`
      })
      const cookie = await res.json();
      console.log('Created cookie value: ', cookie)
      if (res.ok){
        return cookie;
        }
      else{
        console.error('Error while creating the cookie.')
        return ('Error while creating the cookie')
      }
    }
    else{
      console.error('Error while fetching the token from CMS.')
      return ('Error while fetching the token from CMS')
    }
  }
  // Gets the cookie to validate user's email address
  else if (!username && !email && !password && !id){
    const res = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DEPLOY_URL}api/cookie`, {
      method: 'GET'
    });
    const cookie = await res.json();
    console.log('cookie: ', cookie);
    if (res.ok){
      const validated = await fetch(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_JWT_BASE + 'token/validate', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Authorization': `Basic ${cookie.token}`
        },
      });
      console.log('validated: ', validated)
      if(validated.status == 200){
        return cookie;
      }
      else{
        console.error('Error validating the token.')
        return ('Error validating the token');
      }
    }
    else{
      console.log('Cookie not found.')
      return('Please visit your email to validate the submitted address')
    }
  }
  else{
    console.error('Missing required parameters.')
    return ('Wrong parameters. Please try again.')
  }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my humble opinion, you are overcomplicating things.
Go ahead and use Lucia auth. This library manages the cookie creation/retrieval on the server

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).